# mysqli_multi_query() statements executed parallel or one after another?

Tags: mysql

I am executing mysqli_multi_query() with 2 queries in it:

```
UPDATE Customers
    SET balance = balance + 15
    WHERE ck IN 
        (SELECT ck
            FROM Purchases
            WHERE deal_id = 1 AND status = 0);
UPDATE Purchases
    SET status = 3
    WHERE deal_id = 1;
```

before executing queries - there are several records in Purchases table with status=0, however Customers table do not receive updates for some reason. Tested running both queries by hand one after another - all works.
I have a feeling that second UPDATE runs before the first one. Shouldn't they go one after another without processing everything at the same time?

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't: it'd break any functionality that depends on session status, e.g. transactions, for little benefit.

Answer (score 0):

The queries are executed one after another, and it's always the case for as long as your queries are queued via a single MySQL connection.

I have a feeling you are not handling the results correctly. You need to call mysqli_store_result() once after your multi query and then while mysqli_more_results() do mysqli_next_result().

Comment: Yes, single mysql connection. Don't understand why I need mysql_store_result()? there are no results being returned, they're just updates, no rows returned? why these functions? More than that - second query always executes and does the update. First one is the one that doesn't affect any rows.

Comment: @Maris you should call these functions anyway. There was a mentioning on the Internet somewhere that by the time multi_query() returns only the first query is executed. The docs say you should call these functions in any case. Of course there may be something else with your DB and your queries, but first make sure you make these calls properly.

Comment: Hmm, strange. Okay, I guess I'll move back to two separate mysqli_query()